# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection when NOT using a SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I have the following that is throwing a *The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection* exception in the `catch` block.

What I find odd is that nowhere do we create a `SqlParameterCollection`. Each time we create a new instance so the `SqlParameter` is never used more than once. And another oddity is that `test` contains the correct results from the stored procedure and returns the results to the calling method, but when I step one more time from line `3` to `4` is when it decides to enter the catch block. Not at line `33` where I would expect it to occur... If it helps any we switched from an `ObjectContext` to a `DbContext` using the CodeFirst generation tools. All other database interactions and stored procedures used are working as expected.

```
1    try
2    {
3        tempMessages = Context.CheckExistingTables(importSession.ImportSessionID).ToList();
4    }
5    catch (Exception e)
6    {
7        this.LogError("Error validating the import file entities", e);
8        tempMessages.Add(new ErrorMessage() { ErrorType = 3, Message = string.Format("Error validating the import file entities: {0}", e.Message) });
9    }
...
20    public IEnumerable<ErrorMessage> CheckExistingTables(Guid? importSessionID)
21    {
22        SqlParameter importSessionIDParameter;
23
24        if (importSessionID.HasValue)
25        {
26            importSessionIDParameter = new SqlParameter("importSessionID", importSessionID);
27        }
28        else
29        {
30            importSessionIDParameter = new SqlParameter("importSessionID", typeof(System.Guid));
31        }
32
33        var test = Database.SqlQuery<ErrorMessage>("Import.CheckExistingTables @importSessionID", importSessionIDParameter);
34        return test;
35    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So somehow the answer was to call `.ToList()` at the end of line `33`.

Note to others... Add the `using` statment `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file or you won't have the `ToList()` option.

Comment: Thank you very much a quick and easy solution to the issue I was experiencing!